# Add Server Code Dynamically ASP.net webform

Tags: asp.net

I want to add inline server code Dynamically in user control or aspx page like

```
<div>
<% dynamic server side code %>
</div>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: you can write code with `<%= Date.Now %>` for example

Answer (score 0):

Do this using the following code (get year as of now)

```
<%: DateTime.Now.Year %>
```